# Struggling with "simple" chess related randomized code

Tags: python, random

I have as task to create a code that should randomly place two chess pieces on the board

The board looks like this: [Chess board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQiKo.png)

What I should do is "place" two randomly selected chess pieces (one black, one white) on this board above and find out if these pieces fall in places where they would threat each other based on chess rules. I should repeat this 10 000 times and find out how often a threatening situation is met. Pieces should not fall in the same square.

There are two different scenarios:

3a. The chess pieces are rooks(towers) - move horisontally or vertically OR
3b. The chess pieces are queens - move horisontally, vertically and diagonally OR

My assumption is that the approach in 3a should be that if either the first digit or last digit are same for both chess pieces the situation causes a threat. I would use the random-function to assign random numbers for both pieces and run this 10K times. I'm not sure though how to build this code to find out if the chess pieces cause a threat to each other. How to use the chess board (11-88) to define the random numbers?

the approach for 3b is, on the other hand, a big question mark due to the fact that queens can also move diagonally.

I would really appreciate some code example to understand how this is tackled. 
Thanks!

EDIT: Below is the code I generated myself using the skills so far acquired. I believe this gives me the answer of how often a queen threatens another queen BUT it does not take into account that the chess pieces can't be placed on the same square on the board. How could I implement it in my code, taken that the code is otherwise correct? I'd like to modify it as little as possible.

```
import random
rows=range(1,9) #generates the row number
columns=range(97,97+8) #generates the column number
hot=0 #times threat took place
icke_hot=0 #times threat did not take place
for spel in range(10000):
    white_row=random.choice(rows) #Gets position in row
    black_row=random.choice(rows)
    white_column=random.choice(columns) #Gets position in column
    black_column=random.choice(columns)

    if white_column==black_column or white_row==black_row: #checks if rook can attack
        hot=hot+1

    elif white_column==black_column or white_column==black_column+1 or white_column==black_column-1:
        hot=hot+1
        #checks if queen can attack

    elif white_row==black_row or white_row==black_row+1 or white_row==black_row-1:
        hot=hot+1
        #checks if queen can attack
    else:
        icke_hot=icke_hot+1
print "Threats took place in", hot/100.0,"% of cases"
print hot
print icke_hot
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions (showing your own effort as properly formatted code). This is a bit broad and vague. Hint regarding diagonals: Sum and difference of x and y coordinate is important.

Comment: Noted Michael. I'll add some more stuff to my OP. @MichaelButscher

Comment: Why the column coordinates start with 97 instead of 1? It works nevertheless but it is counterintuitive. For diagonal attack checks just note down (maybe in Excel) some coordinates on the same diagonal and look how sum and difference of the row and column coordinates behave.

Comment: A simple way to avoid that the same position is chosen twice is an infinite "while True"-loop around the white random position. As soon as the white position is different from black one, "break" the loop. In theory this can make the program to run forever but in practice this doesn't happen.

Comment: How would you execute this "while True"-loop in practice? I just can't get my head around how it would work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Comments on OP Code**

Column numbering is problematic

```
columns=range(97,97+8) #generates the column number 97, 98, ...
```

You could use

```
columns = [chr(i) for i in range(97,97+8)
```

The following generation of row/columns does not insure that white & black are not assigned the same square.

```
white_row=random.choice(rows) #Gets position in row
black_row=random.choice(rows)
white_column=random.choice(columns) #Gets position in column
black_column=random.choice(columns)
```

It's better to define a position as a row & column pair then
choose randomly two of the 64 positions using either random.choices or random.sample

This code doesn't check for all positions along diagonal for queen attack.

```
elif white_column==black_column or white_column==black_column+1 or white_column==black_column-1:
  hot=hot+1
  #checks if queen can attack

elif white_row==black_row or white_row==black_row+1 or white_row==black_row-1:
  hot=hot+1
  #checks if queen can attack
```

**Revised Code**

```
import random as random

def all_positions():
  " Generates list of all piece positions (i.e. 64 positions) "
  rows = '12345678'                  
  columns = 'abcdefgh'
  return [r+c for r in rows for c in columns] # i.e. ['1a', '1b', ...]

def random_positions():
  " Two random positions (not equal) "
  # Use random sample without replacement
  return random.sample(all_positions(), 2)

def position_to_numeric(position):
  " Convert row, column string to numeric tuple i.e. '3a -> 3, 1 "
  return int(position[0]), 'abcdefgh'.index(position[1]) + 1

def can_rook_attack(position1, position2):
  " Do rooks at position1 and position2 attack each other "
  return position1[0] == position2[0] or position1[1] == position2[1]

def can_queen_attack(position1, position2):
  " if queens at position 1 & 2 can attack each other "

  # Check as rooks they would attack
  if can_rook_attack(position1, position2):
    return True

  # Get positions as numeric
  r1, c1 = position_to_numeric(position1)
  r2, c2 = position_to_numeric(position2)
    # If queen and the opponent are 

  # If queen can attack diagonally  
  return abs(r1 - r2) == abs(c1 - c2)  

def simulate_rooks(number_trials):
  " Simulate of how often rook can attack "
  cnt = 0
  for _ in range(number_trials):
    position1, position2 = random_positions()
    if can_rook_attack(position1, position2):
      cnt += 1

  return f'Rook attacked {cnt} out of {number_trials} random placements'

def simulate_queens(number_trials):
  " Simulate of how often queens can attack "
  cnt = 0
  for _ in range(number_trials):
    position1, position2 = random_positions()
    if can_queen_attack(position1, position2):
      cnt += 1

  return f'Queen attacked {cnt} out of {number_trials} random placements'
```

**Test**

```
simulations = 10000
print(simulate_rooks(simulations))
print(simulate_queens(simulations))
```

**Output**

```
Rook attacked 2257 out of 10000 random placements
Queen attacked 3634 out of 10000 random placements
```

**Explanation**

*Key Issues*

> 1. What I should do is "place" two randomly selected chess pieces (one
>      black, one white) on this board above and find out if these pieces
>      fall in places where they would threat each other based on chess
>      rules. I should repeat this 10 000 times and find out how often a
>      threatening situation is met. Pieces should not fall in the same
>      square.
>
> This is done in simulate_rooks and simulate_queens with the following code

```
for _ in range(number_trials):
    position1, position2 = random_positions()
```

Where random_positions uses random.sample (without replacement) to select two positions out of all possible positions

> 2. My assumption is that the approach in 3a should be that if either the first digit or last digit are same for both chess pieces the situation

This is done with the code in can_rook_attack

```
return position1[0] == position2[0] or position1[1] == position2[1]
```

> 3. the approach for 3b is, on the other hand, a big question mark due to the fact that queens can also move diagonally.

This is solved using:

```
return abs(r1 - r2) == abs(c1 - c2)
```

This uses the constraint that to be along the diagonal the slope has to be +/-1 which leads to the above expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough reply @DarrylG. I really appreciate it. I added my original code to the original post. I would appreciate if you could have a look.

Comment: @Jnathan--updated my post with comments on your code.